# How to install only the Conda Python interpreter without the whole Anaconda package(Spyder, Juyter and so on...)?

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, conda

How to get only the Conda Python interpreter installed without the whole Anaconda package(Spyder, Juyter and so on...)?

How to get only the Conda Python interpreter installed for creating PyCharm scientific projects?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? It's a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) instead of anaconda. The difference is only what comes installed by default. With anaconda the base environment already comes with a lot of packages including the ones you mentioned. On the other hand, with miniconda you only get the bare minimum, including the conda application. Then you can install only what you want.

That is, you can either install anaconda and remove packages or you can install miniconda and install packages and achieve the same result. In case you install miniconda, you can even run `conda install anaconda` if you decide you want all python packages that come already installed with anaconda (anaconda is just a meta package that depends on all packages that come installed when you install anaconda).